# Setting field from resources on declaration on android

Tags: android

Is there any problem with code like this?

```
public class SomeClass extends View {

    private final float someFieldVariable = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.someVariableValue);

    ....

}
```

Comment: yes in order to able to access the resources you need base context for that class

Comment: yes, i forgot to type extends View.

Comment: Then should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is dangerous code.

The context gets wired the time on of the `super`-constructors is called. The initialization of `someFieldVariable` depends on the context and maybe is done before `super` is called.

So there is a chance the context is not wired because of the compiler not being smart enough and then your initialization will fail with an uncaught exeption. This will cause your app to crash.

Even if it works, I think it is bad style to rely on how the compiler does his work.
You should initialize it in your constructors instead to make sure the `super`-connstructor has been called before or just get the value from resources as you need it.

I also think there is no big advantage in defining a local variable for holding a resource value. It is like defining a variable to hold another variable, which is even final. It's just reasonable if you need the value very often and every processor-cycle counts.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I think I'll move the initialization to the constructor.